# Using AJAX to call a PHP (through MSQL) and fill a bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a user list on an HTML table, when I click an entry I have a modal loading through AJAX which should fill a form out with all the relevant information from that user. Information can then be changed and submitted via a change.

I cannot get past getting the modal to load and cannot get data to be loaded into the model.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
$('#editUserModel').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('userID')

         $(function () 
          {

            $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'getUser.php?id=',                          
              data: "recipient",                        

              dataType: 'json',                    
              success: function(data)          
              {
                var id = data[0];              //get id
                var firstName = data[1];       //get name etc...
                var lastName = data[2];
                var username = data[3];
                var password = data[4];
                var jobTitle = data[5];
                var TaskTeam = data[6];
                var admin = data[12];

                var modal = $(this)
                modal.find('.modal-body input').html(username)

              } 
            });
          }); 


    })
</script>
```

Here is the PHP which lists the users (this works and when I click the Edit button a modal loads however the modal is grayed out and shows no underlying data)

```
<?php 
include("dbconnect.php"); 

$dbQuery= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY jobTitle ASC;"); 

while($dbRow = mysql_fetch_array($dbQuery))
{
$userID = $dbRow['id'];
$username = $dbRow['username'];
$firstName = $dbRow['firstName'];
$lastName = $dbRow['lastName'];
$jobTitle = $dbRow['jobTitle'];
$userteam = $dbRow['TaskTeam'];

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary close" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModel" data-userID='.$userID.'><span title="Edit" aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>';
echo '</td>';

echo '<td>'.$firstName.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$lastName.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$jobTitle.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$userteam.'</td>';
echo '<td></td>';

/*
echo '<td>';



echo '</td>';
*/

echo '</tr>';
}

echo mysql_error();
mysql_close();

?>
```

Here is the modal div:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editUserModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="control-label">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName" class="control-label">Surname:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="jobTitle" class="control-label">Job Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobTitle">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="TaskTeam" class="control-label">Task Team:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TaskTeam">
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the php file which retrieves the user data:

```
<?php
  $userID = intval($_GET['id']);
  include("dbconnect.php"); 

  $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $userID";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);    

  echo json_encode($array);

  mysql_close();
?>
```

I don't fully understand PDO, I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: you dont need to learn PDO first. Try transitioning from mysql to mysqli first.

Comment: Questions consisting of "I don't know where the problem is" are going to earn you many downvotes.  The program is doing EXACTLY what it should be doing, the program is "working correctly", and we can't help you make it "work correctly" until you post an error message, or tell us what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Rahter than `mysql` use `mysqli`. Also, the problem is happening because you need to iterate through your rows result. Try this:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$userID = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $userID";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $array = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($array, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Then in your JS, replace the contents of `.success` with this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
            console.log(val);
            //add your functions here

            /*
             var id = data[0];              //get id
             var firstName = data[1];       //get name etc...
             var lastName = data[2];
             var username = data[3];
             var password = data[4];
             var jobTitle = data[5];
             var TaskTeam = data[6];
             var admin = data[12];

             var modal = $(this)
             modal.find('.modal-body input').html(username)
            * 
            */
        });
}
```